# How to select data from the rows and update them in one pass?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I make two queries for one table.

```
SELECT url FROM links WHERE post = '0' AND keywords = 'key';
```

Then

```
UPDATE links SET post='1' WHERE keywords = 'key';
```

But I get a duplicates because many threads.
How to combine these two requests into one?
Thanks

Comment: You _can't_ select and update in a single statement.  You'd need either a stored proc or maybe a transaction to do this.

Comment: hmmm, please more explanation.. what are u trying to achieve?

Comment: @Conan I need to select from the table (links) all the links (url) that correspond to the key (keywords), but at the same time to mark them (post='1'), so that the other thread does not take them again. I will be grateful if you tell me how to implement it in another way.

Comment: Why bother with the select?

Comment: @Strawberry I need to get urls

Answer (score 2):

This is called Race Condition, Give following link a read

http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/how-to/select-update-single-statement-race-condition

Comment: It is good idea to provide reference link but it is possible that link might not be available in the future. So, please provide some description, code in the answer itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
UPDATE links SET post='1' WHERE keywords = 'key' AND post = '0';
```

OR

```
UPDATE links SET post='1' WHERE url in 
(SELECT url FROM links WHERE post = '0' AND keywords = 'key');
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you.

```
UPDATE links SET post='1' WHERE keywords in 
(SELECT keywords FROM links WHERE post = '0' AND keywords = 'key');
```